# Extract coordinates for series of georeferenced files in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have a series of 1900 spatially continuous images that are georeferenced. Each image is a tif file paired with a tfw file.

These images are easily open and shown in ArcMap 10. However, I need a way to extract and tabulate all of their associated coordinates (in this case, the centerpoints of each image) into a spreadsheet.

How do I do this? Please note that I have no scripting abilities.

Thanks!

Comment: Learning to write a script or program will pay for itself the first time you don't have to process 1900 files manually :-).

Comment: @whuber Can't argue with that, unfortunately I need the results in a couple days, and I can't learn scripting fast enough to meet that deadline. :)

Comment: That's the classic argument.  It has been keeping people from realizing their potential for a long time.  I can't speak to your background or abilities, of course, but I would encourage you to learn how to automate your computing work as soon as you possibly can.  You will discover the learning curve may be painful but it is likely faster than you imagine.  You'll never look back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In arcmap 10.
I think I would use the [footprint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000003v000000) feature (in mosaic dataset) and
then generate the [centroid](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32482) of those polygons.
add an x and a y field to my attribute table,
[calculate the geometry](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf),
then [export to dbf](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/11618-Exporting-dbf-layer-file-to-Excel-Spreadsheet) and convert to xls.
Also found in this answer are several resources for esri help.

Comment: That works well - just use model builder to loop it 1900 times and the job is done.

Comment: actually there is no loop to it once you have all the images loaded to the mosaic (which does allow batch).