# Polygon Data to Fit Raster

Tags: raster, polygon, convert, arc-hydro, clip

I'm working with an NHD Flowline of streams and rivers in NC, and I'm trying to only retain the ones in the raster. I tried to convert to the raster to a polygon and was going to clip them, but in the conversion process I received an error. I've attached the area of the study below. My goal is to do a watershed delineation using Arc Hydro.

[image: Watershed area]

Answer (score 2):

When you converted to polygon, the program crashed probably because the polygon file it was creating was too big. So, before converting to polygon, you should reclassify the raster so that it only has one value. Once you have the polygon, you can clip the streams.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can perform a clip, using the raster as the clip extent/mask area.
This may help [How to Clip a Shapefile of Circle features using a Raster using ArcGIS 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/how-to-clip-a-shapefile-of-circle-features-using-a-raster-using-arcgis-10)

Comment: I tried the Extract by Mask tool, but that gives me a raster image of the area of streams.

Comment: If you cannot find a better answer (which I am sure you can) the cheating way would be to create a shape with the extents of the raster then use that new shape as the extent.

Comment: Rather than use a Comment to adjust your Answer, it is preferable to use the edit button beneath to revise it instead.